# Add all query strings on controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple mvc4 application. An action link opens a view with bunch of query string parameters. The view contains a simple form when you click on submit button it posts the form and comes back to the view but I lost the query strings. what I must to do to have same query strings even after you have submitted the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to specify the current request as `action` attribute of your form:

```
<form action="@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

But this will POST to the same resource. If you want to specify a different controller and/or action you could write a custom BeginForm helper which will do the job.

Something along the lines of:

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static IDisposable MyBeginForm(this HtmlHelper html, string controller, string action)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("form");
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
        var query = html.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
        foreach (string key in query)
        {
            routeValues[key] = query[key];
        }

        builder.MergeAttribute("action", urlHelper.Action(action, controller, routeValues));
        builder.MergeAttribute("method", "POST", true);

        html.ViewContext.Writer.Write(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        var form = new MvcForm(html.ViewContext);
        return form;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@using (Html.MyBeginForm("myaction", "mycontroller"))
{
    ...
}
```

This will effectively keep the current url query string parameters.